# inSampleSize vs createScaledBitmap?

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap

AFAIK, the inSampleSize attribute of BitmapFactory.options will read a sampled image as per the `inSampleSize` value. Eg: If value is 4, it will effectively read 1/16 pixels and thus memory required to load it will drastically reduce.
Here in fact, it is maintaining the aspect ratio in the sense that it has skipped 1/4th pixels along height and 1/4th pixels along the width.
When I load this bitmap in a smaller `ImageView`, aspect ratio is maintained and it looks good. I have used the following formula to derive the `inSampleSize = max(Width/reqWidth, height/reqHeight)`
size of the imageview = 100dp * 100dp, I have converted 100dp to pixels as per the screen density and used that result as the reqWidth and reqHeight.
(Note: All my images are bigger than the reqWidth and reqHeight)

However If I apply another operation `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` on above reduced version of bitmap, the image gets stretched and does not look good in the View.

I am not able to understand what `createScaledBitmap()` exactly does?

Answer (score 0):

Given a Bitmap, let's call it bmp1, the [create Scaled bitmap method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) creates a new Bitmap from bmp1 which is upscaled/downscaled to a new size.

However, since you're doing the scaling yourself, perhaps you should simply call `createBitmap()` instead? That one will respect the new size you tell it to be, and won't scale the original image, which is what you want from what i understood.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, however.

Comment: Yes I have tried to createBitmap() directly. It was working fine. However I want to know, what is the purpose of createScaledBitmap. What operation does it do on an image?

Comment: It scales it without modifying the original bitmap.